# Pressing buttons multiple times loads multiple pages (Android)

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

I want to solve the problem, when I push the button several times - offers many of the same pages. I found here such code.

```
var stack = Navigation.NavigationStack;
if (stack[stack.Count - 1].GetType() != typeof(DetailsPage))
await Navigation.PushAsync (new DetailsPage ());
```

`Navigation.NavigationStack` - works fine.
`Navigation.ModalStack` - doesn`t work. But I can`t get Name.

Comment: Disable the button before navigating to the modal page?

Comment: @Bill Reiss . I know this solution, but i think it doesn't good solution.

Comment: @BillReiss solution IS the right one.

Answer (score 8):

there are various threads on this common issue, I can see on the forums that you already commented on it, there are also `NavigationExtensions` class:

```
public static class NavigationExtensions
{
    public static async Task PushModalAsyncSingle(this INavigation nav, Page page, bool animated = false)
    {
        if (App.Navigation.ModalStack.Count == 0 || 
            App.Navigation.ModalStack.Last().GetType() != page.GetType())
        {
            await nav.PushModalAsync(page, animated);
        }
    }

    public static async Task PushAsyncSingle(this INavigation nav, Page page, bool animated = false)
    {
        if (App.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count == 0 ||
            App.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != page.GetType())
        {
            await nav.PushAsync(page, animated);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the discussion:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29787/double-tapping-in-xamarin-forms-on-android