# how to avoid open page already exist on Navigation stack?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am using **Xamarin.forms**, Some times user will click twice on same button, I am search away to avoid open same page twice, maybe disable the button after first click will work fine, but i am searching away to avoid open same page if page already exist on Navigation stack.

```
btnCustomerPage.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
{
 //CustomerPage already Exist on Navigation Stack,So user already open it.
 Navigation.PushAsync(new CustomerPage(); 
};
```

Comment: Just noticed this was responded already with a nicer solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42354382/1771254

Comment: yes, i see .thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count == 0 ||
    Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(CustomerPage))
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new CustomerPage(), true);
}
```

Comment: it is working fine .. thanks

Comment: var _appNavi = App.NavigationPage.Navigation;

            if (_appNavi.NavigationStack.Count == 0 || _appNavi.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(RankPage))
            {
                await _appNavi.PopToRootAsync();
                await _appNavi.PushAsync(new RankPage(), true);
            }
            //App.NavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new RankPage());
            App.MenuIsPresented = false;